# Graphics made by Raphael Javascript in Internet Explorer 8 (IE) have no color. They do in FF and Chrome

Tags: javascript, graphics, graph, internet-explorer-8, raphael

I'm using Raphael javascript library to make graphics.
I've almost copied the Analytics example from the webpage and I'm getting a white and black color graphic in internet explore and I don't know why.

Please see this is how it works on Firefox, Chrome and Safari:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/861/75172783.png/

And this in InternetExplorer:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/847/94131171.png/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the Help.
However, I managed to fix the problem. I don't know why VML didn't like that Raphael object was inside a div with a "-".

This was my structure:

Simply taking the graphic outside the on-data div worked. Very weird actually!

Thanks!

Comment: Hey, what do you mean by 'Raphael object was inside a div with a "-"'? Do you mean a div with an ID with a dash in it?  I'm having issues with Raphael 2.1 in IE 8 and I'm wondering it it's similar... thanks

Comment: I mean a div whose id and class had a -.

Answer (score 0):

From my answer to another Raphael/IE related problem:

Have you tried using [Raphael 2.0](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/tree/2.0)? I think it's still in beta stage, but I found that it's got improved VML capabilities.

Also be sure to test browser behavior with an uncompressed version of Raphael, as minified versions seem to have bugs. Instead, I've used [Packer by Dean Edwards](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/), which gave me a compressed and bug free version of the lib.